# Why is the cost estimate for the first head transplant 100 million USD?

Tags: surgery

I read on https://web.archive.org/web/20171118202503/https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/world/2017/11/17/italian-doctor-says-worlds-first-human-head-transplant-imminent/847288001/:

> An Italian doctor announced Friday that he will soon perform the world’s first human head transplant [...] Canavero estimates the procedure will **cost up to $100 million** and involve several dozen surgeons and other specialists.

What can explain such a high cost?

Comment: If a top surgeon costs 100k per month, the project takes 3 years and there are "several dozen" surgeons, let's say 30 you will get: 100.000*12*3*30=108m

Comment: @user1721135 Where did you read that the project requires 3 years full-time for the "several dozen" surgeons involved?

Comment: A project like this requires insane amounts of R&D and preparation. I am most likely grossly underestimating the costs and time.

Answer (score 0):

we can only take guesses but one can assume: chemicals, hours involved, and the number of surgeons I believe he said was 100+ one of which being [Ren Xiaoping](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Xiaoping_Ren).

other operations as such after the fact i'm uncertain if a caretaker will be provided, but that would inquire them to know nearly as much as Zen or Canavero would about the effects of the surgery.

perhaps he is also imploring all previous works such as the transplants done on the lab rats that didn't survive very long.[this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmG83iOEvH4)

on the contrary it has also been mentioned that the reduced rate would be |[13Mil$](https://answersdrive.com/how-much-does-it-cost-to-get-a-brain-transplant-3370) [13Mil$](https://www.ibtimes.com.au/head-transplant-procedure-cost-13-million-1437989)| instead of 100Mil$.

*postscript* a lot of people say that the surgery will be a minimum of 13mil$ but don't give a reason as to why, this is because Ren Xiaoping and Sergio Canavero have given little to no information on how this surgery actually works,

and until someone on the surgery team actually gives us a better idea of what goes on during a head transplant which they have not we can only make estimations on why it costs so much and can't actually pull proper figures.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. We work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.

Comment: I fail to see how this question in particular could effect the health of an individual, would this edit be sufficient? documentation has been added. but it says the same thing. which is basically, "we don't really know".

Comment: The edits you made are fine. We don't require extensive references, just sufficient to establish the credibility of your factual claims.

Comment: I just find it a bit strange, and perhaps even backwards to reference essentially a "we don't know" answer. sort of like doing this [or idk.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Don%27t_Know)

Comment: Maybe you're wrong and we do know. If you can't find a single credible source that agrees with you, then there's a problem. Right?